# Java Error: C [javaHeclib.dll+0x197d5a]

Tags: java

I am running an automation script for [HEC-HMS](http://www.hec.usace.army.mil/software/hec-hms/) simulation but I got this error:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x29337d5a, pid=10404, tid=10800
#
# JRE version: 6.0_19-b04
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (16.2-b04 mixed mode windows-x86 )
# Problematic frame:
# C  [javaHeclib.dll+0x197d5a]
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://java.sun.com/webapps/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00679c00):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=10800, stack(0x007c0000,0x00810000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, writing address 0x7c15d4a8

Registers:
EAX=0x14b1e929, EBX=0x29917a70, ECX=0x14b1e942, EDX=0x29917a70
ESP=0x0080e684, EBP=0x0080e728, ESI=0x00000007, EDI=0x296c6e80
EIP=0x29337d5a, EFLAGS=0x00010293

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0080e684)
0x0080e684:   000001f8 000001fd 0080e6fc 292fbc57
0x0080e694:   29557d04 29557d00 2948d504 2912027f
0x0080e6a4:   29557d04 00000000 00000000 00000000
0x0080e6b4:   00000000 0000001c 00000030 00000030
0x0080e6c4:   00000030 00000030 0000a6ef 0000000b
0x0080e6d4:   0000a800 0000001c 00000000 00000000
0x0080e6e4:   00000040 00000000 00000030 00000030
0x0080e6f4:   fffffb81 00000030 00000000 00000004 

Instructions: (pc=0x29337d5a)
0x29337d4a:   44 24 10 e8 f8 31 f6 ff 83 c4 14 a1 04 30 4e 29
0x29337d5a:   c7 04 85 04 30 4e 29 ff ff ff ff 57 8b 45 08 89 


Stack: [0x007c0000,0x00810000],  sp=0x0080e684,  free space=1390080dc34k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [javaHeclib.dll+0x197d5a]
C  [javaHeclib.dll+0x1b3783]
C  [javaHeclib.dll+0x17e139]
C  [javaHeclib.dll+0x11aa23]
j  hec.heclib.util.Heclib.Hec_zsrtsc([ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;II[F[D[IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[DI[IILjava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;IIFIII[I)V+0
j  hec.heclib.util.Heclib.zsrtsc([ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;II[F[D[IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[DI[IILjava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;IIFIII[I)V+48
j  hec.heclib.dss.HecTimeSeries.flushToDisk()I+521
j  hec.heclib.dss.HecTimeSeries.write(Z)I+17
j  hec.heclib.dss.HecTimeSeries.write([DIZ)I+8
j  hms.model.data.HmsTimeSeries.write([DIZ)I+4
j  hms.model.data.l.e(I)V+45
j  hms.model.met.ae.c(I)V+5
j  hms.model.met.ae.p()I+7
j  hms.model.met.j.a(DZ)I+337
j  hms.model.met.aD.a(Ljava/util/List;Ljava/lang/String;)I+375
j  hms.model.met.aN.b(Ljava/util/List;ZLhec/heclib/util/HecTime;Ljava/lang/String;)I+234
j  hms.model.Project.computePrecip(Ljava/util/List;ZLhms/model/a/ay;Ljava/lang/String;Lhec/heclib/util/HecTime;)I+174
j  hms.model.Project.computeModel(Ljava/util/List;ZZZLjava/lang/String;)I+1209
j  hms.model.Project.computeModel(ZZZ)I+153
j  hms.model.Project.compute(Z)I+11
j  hms.model.JythonHms.Compute(Ljava/lang/String;)V+28
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0xf049c]
V  [jvm.dll+0x17fcf1]
V  [jvm.dll+0xf051d]
V  [jvm.dll+0x199ceb]
V  [jvm.dll+0x19a706]
V  [jvm.dll+0x11bc03]
C  [java.dll+0x714d]
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+161
j  org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction.__call__(Lorg/python/core/PyObject;[Lorg/python/core/PyObject;[Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/python/core/PyObject;+249
j  org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction.__call__([Lorg/python/core/PyObject;[Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/python/core/PyObject;+4
j  org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(Lorg/python/core/PyObject;)Lorg/python/core/PyObject;+12
j  org.python.pycode._pyx0.f$0(Lorg/python/core/PyFrame;)Lorg/python/core/PyObject;+46
j  org.python.pycode._pyx0.call_function(ILorg/python/core/PyFrame;)Lorg/python/core/PyObject;+22
j  org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Lorg/python/core/PyFrame;Lorg/python/core/PyObject;)Lorg/python/core/PyObject;+230
j  org.python.core.PyCode.call(Lorg/python/core/PyFrame;)Lorg/python/core/PyObject;+3
j  org.python.core.Py.runCode(Lorg/python/core/PyCode;Lorg/python/core/PyObject;Lorg/python/core/PyObject;)Lorg/python/core/PyObject;+70
j  org.python.core.__builtin__.execfile_flags(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/python/core/PyObject;Lorg/python/core/PyObject;Lorg/python/core/CompilerFlags;)V+71
j  org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.execfile(Ljava/lang/String;)V+17
j  hms.model.JythonHms.runScript(Ljava/lang/String;)I+118
j  hms.Hms.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+382
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0xf049c]
V  [jvm.dll+0x17fcf1]
V  [jvm.dll+0xf051d]
V  [jvm.dll+0xf9bc5]
V  [jvm.dll+0x10181d]
C  [java.exe+0x2155]
C  [java.exe+0x85b4]
C  [KERNEL32.DLL+0x18744]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x6582d]
C  [ntdll.dll+0x657fd]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  hec.heclib.util.Heclib.Hec_zsrtsc([ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;II[F[D[IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[DI[IILjava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;IIFIII[I)V+0
j  hec.heclib.util.Heclib.zsrtsc([ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;II[F[D[IILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;[DI[IILjava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;IIFIII[I)V+48
j  hec.heclib.dss.HecTimeSeries.flushToDisk()I+521
j  hec.heclib.dss.HecTimeSeries.write(Z)I+17
j  hec.heclib.dss.HecTimeSeries.write([DIZ)I+8
j  hms.model.data.HmsTimeSeries.write([DIZ)I+4
j  hms.model.data.l.e(I)V+45
j  hms.model.met.ae.c(I)V+5
j  hms.model.met.ae.p()I+7
j  hms.model.met.j.a(DZ)I+337
j  hms.model.met.aD.a(Ljava/util/List;Ljava/lang/String;)I+375
j  hms.model.met.aN.b(Ljava/util/List;ZLhec/heclib/util/HecTime;Ljava/lang/String;)I+234
j  hms.model.Project.computePrecip(Ljava/util/List;ZLhms/model/a/ay;Ljava/lang/String;Lhec/heclib/util/HecTime;)I+174
j  hms.model.Project.computeModel(Ljava/util/List;ZZZLjava/lang/String;)I+1209
j  hms.model.Project.computeModel(ZZZ)I+153
j  hms.model.Project.compute(Z)I+11
j  hms.model.JythonHms.Compute(Ljava/lang/String;)V+28
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+0
j  sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+87
j  sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+6
j  java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Ljava/lang/Object;[Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object;+161
j  org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction.__call__(Lorg/python/core/PyObject;[Lorg/python/core/PyObject;[Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/python/core/PyObject;+249
j  org.python.core.PyReflectedFunction.__call__([Lorg/python/core/PyObject;[Ljava/lang/String;)Lorg/python/core/PyObject;+4
j  org.python.core.PyObject.__call__(Lorg/python/core/PyObject;)Lorg/python/core/PyObject;+12
j  org.python.pycode._pyx0.f$0(Lorg/python/core/PyFrame;)Lorg/python/core/PyObject;+46
j  org.python.pycode._pyx0.call_function(ILorg/python/core/PyFrame;)Lorg/python/core/PyObject;+22
j  org.python.core.PyTableCode.call(Lorg/python/core/PyFrame;Lorg/python/core/PyObject;)Lorg/python/core/PyObject;+230
j  org.python.core.PyCode.call(Lorg/python/core/PyFrame;)Lorg/python/core/PyObject;+3
j  org.python.core.Py.runCode(Lorg/python/core/PyCode;Lorg/python/core/PyObject;Lorg/python/core/PyObject;)Lorg/python/core/PyObject;+70
j  org.python.core.__builtin__.execfile_flags(Ljava/lang/String;Lorg/python/core/PyObject;Lorg/python/core/PyObject;Lorg/python/core/CompilerFlags;)V+71
j  org.python.util.PythonInterpreter.execfile(Ljava/lang/String;)V+17
j  hms.model.JythonHms.runScript(Ljava/lang/String;)I+118
j  hms.Hms.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+382
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x2970a000 JavaThread "Timer-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10644, stack(0x29060000,0x290b0000)]
  0x0246c400 JavaThread "Low Memory Detector" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10248, stack(0x28a80000,0x28ad0000)]
  0x0246b400 JavaThread "CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=1852, stack(0x289f0000,0x28a40000)]
  0x02469c00 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12232, stack(0x28960000,0x289b0000)]
  0x02467c00 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10360, stack(0x288d0000,0x28920000)]
  0x02449000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7232, stack(0x28840000,0x28890000)]
  0x02447c00 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10372, stack(0x287b0000,0x28800000)]
=>0x00679c00 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=10800, stack(0x007c0000,0x00810000)]

Other Threads:
  0x02445000 VMThread [stack: 0x28720000,0x28770000] [id=10060]
  0x02471c00 WatcherThread [stack: 0x28b10000,0x28b60000] [id=7048]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 def new generation   total 9792K, used 3488K [0x044d0000, 0x04f70000, 0x0ef70000)
  eden space 8704K,  40% used [0x044d0000, 0x04837bc0, 0x04d50000)
  from space 1088K,   0% used [0x04d50000, 0x04d505e0, 0x04e60000)
  to   space 1088K,   0% used [0x04e60000, 0x04e60000, 0x04f70000)
 tenured generation   total 21888K, used 13786K [0x0ef70000, 0x104d0000, 0x244d0000)
   the space 21888K,  62% used [0x0ef70000, 0x0fce6b20, 0x0fce6c00, 0x104d0000)
 compacting perm gen  total 12288K, used 9536K [0x244d0000, 0x250d0000, 0x284d0000)
   the space 12288K,  77% used [0x244d0000, 0x24e203c0, 0x24e20400, 0x250d0000)
No shared spaces configured.

Dynamic libraries:
0x00400000 - 0x00424000     C:\Program Files (x86)\HEC\HEC-HMS\3.5\java\bin\java.exe
0x778e0000 - 0x77a6e000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x74760000 - 0x74830000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x76200000 - 0x763c2000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x72a90000 - 0x72b23000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\apphelp.dll
0x76930000 - 0x769a7000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x74ae0000 - 0x74b9d000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
0x748d0000 - 0x74911000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
0x760e0000 - 0x761a0000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
0x74390000 - 0x743b0000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\SspiCli.dll
0x74380000 - 0x7438a000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\CRYPTBASE.dll
0x77000000 - 0x77057000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x7c340000 - 0x7c396000     C:\Program Files (x86)\HEC\HEC-HMS\3.5\java\bin\msvcr71.dll
0x6d8b0000 - 0x6db47000     C:\Program Files (x86)\HEC\HEC-HMS\3.5\java\bin\client\jvm.dll
0x74bf0000 - 0x74d2c000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
0x77770000 - 0x77786000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
0x74730000 - 0x74751000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
0x74440000 - 0x74598000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
0x745a0000 - 0x74619000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcp_win.dll
0x77060000 - 0x77178000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
0x73b60000 - 0x73b84000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x73b30000 - 0x73b53000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\winmmbase.dll
0x77720000 - 0x77759000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x74ba0000 - 0x74bc5000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.DLL
0x6d860000 - 0x6d86c000     C:\Program Files (x86)\HEC\HEC-HMS\3.5\java\bin\verify.dll
0x6d3e0000 - 0x6d3ff000     C:\Program Files (x86)\HEC\HEC-HMS\3.5\java\bin\java.dll
0x6d340000 - 0x6d348000     C:\Program Files (x86)\HEC\HEC-HMS\3.5\java\bin\hpi.dll
0x74620000 - 0x74626000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\PSAPI.DLL
0x6d8a0000 - 0x6d8af000     C:\Program Files (x86)\HEC\HEC-HMS\3.5\java\bin\zip.dll
0x28d60000 - 0x28e19000     C:\Program Files (x86)\HEC\HEC-HMS\3.5\jniLibHydro.dll
0x74a50000 - 0x74a69000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\imagehlp.dll
0x6d0b0000 - 0x6d1fa000     C:\Program Files (x86)\HEC\HEC-HMS\3.5\java\bin\awt.dll
0x74630000 - 0x74723000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ole32.dll
0x763d0000 - 0x76608000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
0x73da0000 - 0x73e0e000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\WINSPOOL.DRV
0x73d60000 - 0x73d78000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\bcrypt.dll
0x725a0000 - 0x727ae000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\x86_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.15063.483_none_6dad63fefc436da8\COMCTL32.dll
0x64780000 - 0x649d4000     C:\WINDOWS\AppPatch\AcGenral.DLL
0x76670000 - 0x766b5000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHLWAPI.dll
0x74830000 - 0x748c6000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\OLEAUT32.dll
0x74d80000 - 0x760c8000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\SHELL32.dll
0x735a0000 - 0x73618000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\UxTheme.dll
0x70170000 - 0x70185000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\samcli.dll
0x743b0000 - 0x7443c000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\shcore.dll
0x6eec0000 - 0x6eed8000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSACM32.dll
0x730d0000 - 0x730d8000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x77180000 - 0x77707000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\windows.storage.dll
0x769b0000 - 0x769be000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
0x74d30000 - 0x74d75000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\powrprof.dll
0x760d0000 - 0x760e0000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\profapi.dll
0x730a0000 - 0x730c2000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\USERENV.dll
0x73990000 - 0x739b3000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\dwmapi.dll
0x72c30000 - 0x72dcc000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\urlmon.dll
0x6d700000 - 0x6d716000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MPR.dll
0x72870000 - 0x72a83000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\iertutil.dll
0x28e30000 - 0x28e54000     C:\Program Files (x86)\HEC\HEC-HMS\3.5\WindowsEnvironment.dll
0x291a0000 - 0x296a3000     C:\Program Files (x86)\HEC\HEC-HMS\3.5\javaHeclib.dll
0x6d6c0000 - 0x6d6d3000     C:\Program Files (x86)\HEC\HEC-HMS\3.5\java\bin\net.dll
0x74a70000 - 0x74ad7000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll
0x73a80000 - 0x73ace000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\mswsock.dll
0x6d6e0000 - 0x6d6e9000     C:\Program Files (x86)\HEC\HEC-HMS\3.5\java\bin\nio.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false -DMapPanel.NoVolatileImage=true -Xms32M -Xmx512M -Dpython.path=.;.\hms.jar;.\ui;.\lib\commons-math.jar;.\lib\jython.jar;.\lib\jdom.jar;.\lib\serializer.jar;.\lib\xalan.jar;.\lib\xercesImpl.jar;.\lib\xml-apis.jar;.\lib\Environment.jar;.\lib\MrSidReader.jar;.\lib\images.jar;.\lib\jh.jar -Djava.library.path=. 
java_command: hms.Hms -s C:\MainitTubayWLForecasting\HECHMSModel\MainitTubay_HECHMS\forecast.script
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java
JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre7
PATH=C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Python27;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\OSGeo4W\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\NetCDF4Excel;C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Heroku\bin;C:\Users\acer\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\acer\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Python27;
USERNAME=acer
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 60 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows NT 6.2 Build 9200 

CPU:total 8 (8 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 60 stepping 3, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, ht

Memory: 4k page, physical 8312428k(4062692k free), swap 16701036k(10588872k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (16.2-b04) for windows-x86 JRE (1.6.0_19-b04), built on Mar  9 2010 00:48:41 by "java_re" with MS VC++ 7.1 (VS2003)

time: Mon Oct 23 09:12:50 2017
elapsed time: 5 seconds
```

However, this does not occur running another automation script.
What could be the issue here?
I am not familiar with Java, the automation script mainly uses batch scripting, Python and a little bit of Jython (which is just a one line code) for HEC-HMS simulation.

Comment: Sounds like a bug in that native library `javaHeclib.dll` (invalid memory access), see what is necessary to reproduce this and report a bug to the authors of HEC-HMS.

Comment: Uhhmmn..But I was able to run another automation script without a problem.

Comment: Well, you are also using a very old version of Java 6, try a higher update of Java 6 or even a newer version of Java, but `EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005)` means it tries to access memory it isn't allowed to, or tries to write to memory that is read-only. And as this occurs in `javaHeclib.dll` it is very likely a bug.

Comment: Ok, Thanks..I'll update my Java version